# jquery mobile performing faster than plain html on a non-wifi internet connection

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4, iphone-3gs

I am having a very strange issue with my MVC 4 Web Application.
Until recently, we used jquery mobile 1.1 as basis of our UI and basic actions (in additon to the MVC framework).
recently we realized that the performance of our web-app on mobile phone is not sufficient. 
we removed all references to jquery and the performance got a lot better.
But, we are now facing a new, weird issue: especially on iPhones, if the web-app is loaded with a non-wifi (3G) internet connection, all html pages load extremely slow. on WIFI it is OK.
Does anyone have an idea why html web pages are loading very slowly on 3G connections without jquery mobile?
can it be related to 3Gs? does jquery-mobile do any optimizations on these connections?
also note that on android devices the performance is OK

Comment: It sounds like your WiFi connection is just a lot faster than your 3G connection (which makes sense). jQuery Mobile is completely client-side, so it does nothing until it's completely loaded onto the client device.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I thought about that option but still, if I run the app with jquery and a 3G connection it's still much faster - so I still can't see why this makes a difference

Comment: I don't think you'll get much help with the way you've asked your question. What in all is different since the removal of jQuery Mobile, are you including other frameworks instead? Were you using CDN hosted jQuery Mobile files or hosting them yourself (and the same question for the non-jQuery Mobile version)?